# Characters with diacritics are converted to ascii

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, character-encoding

I am trying to fetch the value from TextArea with max 500 characters. But I am facing a problem with characters with diacritics where each special character is replaced by 4 characters. As a consequence if I give text of 500 characters that includes French characters, the actual length required to persist in Database (field length is 500) is exceeding 500 chars and the transaction fails.

Some examples:

- oubliée is converted to oubliÃƒÂ©e
- désiriez is converted to dÃƒÂ©siriez

Can someone correct me if I am doing wrong or how to fetch the actual text entered by user in Java code?
I am using the following snippets of code:

Form definition:

```
<form id="contForm" method="post" name="formCont"
    action="/wps/customforms/ParticipationRequest"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

TextArea definition:

```
<div class="spec textarea small" id="inpSpec">
    <label class="label" for="inp"><%=content.getLangMap().get(langcode)%>
        <span class="required">*</span> <span class="hint"></span> </label>
    <div class="value">
        <div class="control">
            <textarea cols="5" rows="3"
                id="<%=String.valueOf(content.getId())%>"
                name="<%=String.valueOf(content.getId())%>"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Servlet snippet:

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
String description = null;
for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.isFormField()) {
                if (item.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(content.getId()))) {

                        // Here I get invalid data for french characters.
                        description =  item.getString());
                    }
        }
}
```

Additional information:

- Application server used: WAS
- Platform: Linux
- I tried to set character encoding type of the request as UTF-8, iso-8951... but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

All characters above 127 in utf-8 are escaped in two or more bytes. You seem to have an encoding mismatch between a data writer and a data writer:

- a text showing `Ã©` is typical of some french accents characters saved as utf-8 encoding but later read as latin-1 (aka iso-8859-1) : the `é` (hex `E9`) in latin-1 when saved in utf-8 becomes `C3 A9` ( = `Ã©` if displayed as "raw" characters)
- but if `Ã©` in its turn is saved as utf-8, it becomes `C3 83 C2 A9` that shows as `ÃƒÂ©` is displayed as raw characters or latin encoding

I don't know your application server, but look where the text could be written as utf-8 but read as plain iso-8859 / latin text .

Comment: We are using WAS (Websphere Application Server)